# Programming error at all URLS in django, postgres cannot find tables in db?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku-postgres

My Django project works fine locally on my machine, but when I deployed it to Heroku. I'm getting an error for all of my urls. My urls include:

admin/
blog/
projects/

When I type in a different url, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /blog/
relation "blog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t"."last_modified", "blog_post"."created_on" FROM "blog_post.
```

This occurs at every url. Looking at the traceback, it seems like it has to do with the Templates. Here is the traceback:

```
Template error:
In template /app/personal_portfolio/templates/base.html, error at line 3
   relation "blog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t"."last_modified", "blog_post"."created_on" FROM "blog_post...
```

and

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "blog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t"."last_modified", "blog_post"."created_on" FROM "blog_post...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/blog/views.py" in blog_index
  12.     return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)
```

I'm also thinking it has something to do with the tables/database. I'm currently using SQLite on my local machine, but I know heroku is using postgres.

I've deleted the migrations folders in every app and deleted the db. I've then run makemigrations and migrate multiple times.

Comment: Where are you running `migrate`?

Comment: Did you actually configure your project to use postgres on Heroku? How?

Comment: Yeah, if you type in heroku addons in the terminal you can see what databases you have connected to you app and I have post gres.

Comment: @IainShelvington I’m running migrations locally then I push it to heroku

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410107/running-manage-py-migrate-during-heroku-deployment

Answer (score 0):

Either you are forget to migrate or you are not connected to the database.

Comment: I’ve run migrations on my local machine and then pushed to it to heroku. How would I check if I’m connected to the dB on heroku? Heroku addons?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410107/running-manage-py-migrate-during-heroku-deployment